# Como passar parâmetro para o construtor de um Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como eu posso injetar um parâmetro para o construtor do meu Controller?

Tenho o `CategoriasController` com um construtor que espera o `IAppServiceCategories appService`, quando chamo me retorna um erro.

```
using ProjetoModelo.Application.Interfaces;
using ProjetoModelo.Domain.Entidades;
using ProjetoModelo.MVC.AutoMapper;
using ProjetoModelo.MVC.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjetoModelo.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class CategoriasController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppServiceCategories _AppServiceCategories;

        public CategoriasController(IAppServiceCategories appService)
        {
            _AppServiceCategories = appService;
        }
        // GET: Categoria
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var categoriesViewModel = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Categories>, IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel>>(_AppServiceCategories.GetAll());
            return View(categoriesViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor
>   sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual
>   solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da
>   exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de
>   exceção abaixo.
>
> Rastreamento de Pilha:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido
>   para este objeto.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +247    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'ProjetoModelo.MVC.Controllers.CategoriasController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +191    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319;
>   Versão do ASP.NET:4.7.2053.0

Comment: Não sei onde errei na pergunta, mas caso tenha que complementar, me avisem ao dar um -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa instalar no seu projeto um *framework* de Injeção de Dependência (DI).

O [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/) por exemplo.

Usando o *Unity* você precisa registrar e mapear o tipo concreto que será injetado quando você passa sua interface (*IAppServiceCategories*) no construtor do controller (*CategoriasController*).

Exemplo:

```
// Cria uma instância do container de DI
var container = new UnityContainer(); 

// Registra o tipo concreto que será injetado
container.RegisterType<IAppServiceCategories, AppServiceCategories>();
```

Você precisará criar uma classe responsável por essa configuração e no método *Application_Start* do arquivo *Global.asax.cs* chamar o método para carregar essa configuração do *container*. Ou seja, iniciando sua aplicação você já configura no Unity *container* suas dependências.

São necessários alguns detalhes para instalar e configurar, então recomendo que você dê uma olhada [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection).

Comment: legal, vlw.....

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o Asp Net Core ele ja vem com um injetor de dependências próprio, ai é só assinar no método ConfigureServices da classe Startup.
DICA!!!!!